# How can to check if type is unsigned int or signed int in Java ?

Tags: java, types, int, unsigned-integer

How to check if type is unsigned int or signed int in Java ? 
 I used object.getExpressionType() to know type in Java, but it is showing or giving only long, int but not unsigned int or signed int. I am new to java can someone help me with this ? Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Surprisingly, Java has no unsigned integers.
There is no way to exclude negative numbers using data type, only through program logic.

Comment: It's worth noting that there is some support for using regular `int`s as unsigned ints in Java 8, although there is no type safety: https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/unsigned_api

Answer (score 2):

As range of values of unsigned int is from 0 to 4294967295, you can implement it like this:

```
   public static boolean isValid(long val) {
   if ( (val < 0)  || (val > 4294967295L))
       return false;
   else
       return true; }
```